# gRPC - Detect connection changes when there are no active rpc calls

Tags: c#, networking, grpc

I've been exploring this issue for a while with no success. I'm developing a client/server application with communication based on gRPC.

I have a use case where I need to be notified on disconnected client. (cleaning resource, notifying other back-ends, etc.)

As I understand, gRPC does not provide any hook on connection changes, when there's no active rpc call.

I've also tried to set all the parameters for 'keep-alive' on the channel, both on client and server, with the intent of somehow intercepting it on the server, with no success.

I need help to understand if i'm missing something. Thanks

```
public IEnumerable<ChannelOption> Options { get; set; } = new[]
    {
        new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_time_ms", 5000),
        new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms", 5000),
        new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls", 1),
        new ChannelOption("GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MAX_PINGS_WITHOUT_DATA", 0),
        new ChannelOption("grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms", 5000),
        new ChannelOption("grpc.http2.min_ping_interval_without_data_ms", 5000)
    };
```

Comment: I have a pattern that I use to detect from the client, when a server goes away.  I mainly do this to support updating a UI so that certain calls are disabled.  But I have not seen anything that will let you know a client is no longer available.

Comment: @RobGoodwin thanks man. Do you use some sort of keep alive logic? Maybe by issuing a server/client stream from/to server/ui it's possible to detect connection changes, but i'm interested to achieve that without this option.

Comment: From the client, you can call the TryWaitForStateChangeAsync from the channel.  If you have that running in a task, and call the channel.ConnectAsync() you will be notified when the client connects to the server, and when it the connection is lost. No pings, or streaming needed.  I can write up some more details in an answer if you want, but I think your question was more the server detecting lost clients.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm interested in doing so on the server side. Thanks.